# How do I disable reels in my Facebook group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I have a Facebook group and when I upload a video there, it automatically displays as a reel. Is there any way to disable reels in a Facebook group?

Comment: Have you reviewed [Add and manage features for a Facebook group you admin](https://m.facebook.com/help/166599882185672/computer-help/)?